# Cakephp database migration error

Tags: cakephp

I am using Ubuntu + cakephp 1.3. I am trying the database migration with the help of cakeDC migration plugin. I configured the plugin as per the instructions.

But when i goes to the terminal, goes to the path of the application application_path/app/ dir then fire a command 'cake migration help' it gives me following error,

Hello user,

### Welcome to CakePHP v1.2 Console

Current Paths:
 -working: /path/to/cake/
 -root: /path/to/cake/
 -app: /path/to/cake/app/
 -core: /path/to/cake/

Changing Paths:
your working path should be the same as your application path
to change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

app/vendors/shells/:
         - none

vendors/shells/:
         - none

cake/console/libs/:
         acl
         api
         bake
         console
         extract

To run a command, type 'cake shell_name [args]'
To get help on a specific command, type 'cake shell_name help'

Then i followed the steps given in the : 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/108/The-CakePHP-Console

$ cake -app /path/to/app

But i am not getting the success. Can anybody help me out from this issue...

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: type `whereis cake`. you say you are using 1.3, but that is the 1.2 shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing cake shell, which is somewhere in your `$PATH` (type `which cake` to see which one comes in `$PATH` first). To run cake shell belonging to your app (version 1.3), execute `/path/to/your/application/cake/console/cake` (if you're in your /app dir, simply execute `../cake/console/cake`) with any options you may need (like `-app`).