# Cakephp 1.3 database migration with

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3 on LAMP (ubuntu 9.04) platform.
Trying the database migration with cakephp inbuilt schema generation script.
I am inside the app folder & When i fire a command in the terminal 'cake schema run create schema file name', It is giving me the error that "Error:schema.php could not be included."

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786956/cakephp-database-migration-error

Answer (score 0):

http://amilaudana.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/how-to-install-cakephp-console-on-ubuntu/

it' working

Comment: Hey Karl,

Thanks for the solution. It is working fine now. :)